# Nimbus Look And Feel JTabbedPane Tab Background Color

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I want to change the white background behind the tabs. I tried to set different UIDefaults in UIManager to no avail. I thought changing the panel inside the tabbedpane would do it but it also didn't. Does anyone know how?

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
                defaults.put("Table.gridColor", new Color (214,217,223));
                defaults.put("Table.selectionBackground", new Color(250,235,215));
                defaults.put("Table.selectionForeground", Color.BLACK);
                defaults.put("TabbedPane.background", new Color(175, 238, 238));

                MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: Modify the White Background behind the Row of Tabs]

Answer (score 1):

This will simply be the background color of the parent component. For example if the component is directly added to a `JFrame`

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Good idea is to enclose the tabbed pane into a panel, provide background for this panel and make it opaque. The problem is that the Nimbus L&F extends Synth L&F and therefore is hard to recustomize.